# How to disable a button after clicked in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

In this code i try to disable a button after clicking in Ionic 2

```
<button ion-button icon-only icon-left (click)="AddMarker()" ng-disabled="clicked" color="light"><ion-icon name="locate" ></ion-icon> </button>
```

but it is still the same and when clicking the function is calling.

I add this

Comment: Where's the button? How is this input field related, didn't you want to disable a button, what is the function you are talking about? :)

Comment: excuse me i've posted  wrong ling I have updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var disabled = false;

AddMarker()
{
this.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button ion-button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="disabled=true">
Click me to disable
</button>

<button ion-button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="AddMarker()">
Click me to disable
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make the clicked button to disable.

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="disabled=true">
Click me to disable
</button>
```

If you are using a method in your component use the below code

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="AddMarker()">
Click me to disable
</button>
```

Method

```
AddMarker(){
     this.disabled="true";    
}
```

Comment: so where had to call `AddMarker()`